# Posting to Friends Wall

Tags: facebook

In the new PHP SDK is there any way to post to a friends wall?

I have seen several apps do it. Like apps that say "your friend asked you a question", and I'm not even a user of that app. Is there any way to do it?

I am using an FBML canvas. I already have all the users friends, just need to figure out how to post to the friends they select from the list.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, as long as you have the **publish_stream** [extended permission](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions)

> Enables your application to post
>   content, comments, and likes to a
>   user's stream **and to the streams of
>   the user's friends**, without
>   prompting the user each time.

As far as publishing goes

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api#publishing

Comment: With February 2013 breaking changes this won't work anymore (http://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the facebook api method below, this works with the 3.1.1 SDK:

```
$publishStream = $facebook->api("/$user/feed", 'post', array(
     'message' => "Your Message", 
     'link'    => 'http://example.com',
     'picture' => '',
     'name'    => 'App Name',
     'description'=> 'App description'
));
```

Just replace the $user variable with the user id of your friend.